# @ConfigurationProperties reload after programmatically add active profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, configurationproperties

I have a class that's annotated with @ConfigurationProperties.

```
@ConfigurationProperties
@Configuration
@DependsOn("AddDefaultProfile")
public class MyProperties(){
 ....
}
```

I have several profiles that's `chrome, safari, ie, and en_US, fr_CA` etc.
My running param looks like `-Dspring.profiles.active=chrome, en_US`.

Now I want to check if language is specified, if not, I add a default language to it using `environment.addActiveProfile("en_US")`.
The problem is my MyProperties doesn't get reload.
By debugging it, I can see environment has en_US in active profile, but propertySource still has the old profiles.

How can I make MyProperties reload with my new profile.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to call this method `WebApplicationContextUtils#initServletPropertySources(org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources, javax.servlet.ServletContext, javax.servlet.ServletConfig)`, but i m not sure this is useful

Answer (score 0):

In spring boot there are among others:

- application.properties (loaded in any case)
- application-abc.properties (loaded only if profile abc is active)

These are the source files where the actual values can be located.

`@ConfigurationProperties` however means that after all the relevant files to load are located, how to "prepare" the actual key-values that spring-boot reads to be used in the application (for example, injecting the bean marked with `@ConfigurationProperties`, etc)

So, I guess, you should put the defaults in just `application.properties` and profile specific stuff into `application-<profile>.properties`

Profile specific stuff will always take precedence over the default, so you'll end up with the following:

- When profile is not specified, stuff from *application.properties* will be loaded
- When profile is specified, actual values will be loaded from `application-<profile>.properties`, despite the fact that the same property key was defined in *application.properties* file

Having said that another way is to always use a profile, just define a default profile and load it explicitly (--spring.profiles.active=default) and keep your stuff in *application-default.properties*

If you want to programmatically define an active profile by checking that other profiles do not exist you can implement an [EnvironmentPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/env/EnvironmentPostProcessor.html) but its a pretty advanced stuff already